# Using Task with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I am trying to get some asynchronous work done with the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` class. The scenario is simple. I have a web app and in one button click event I start a Task which must run to check some outside service for a couple of minutes. It is not a heavy task. All it's going to do is send a request every 5 seconds and get a response. But it must do it for at least a couple of minutes. So, I don't want user to wait until this task gets job done. After I have started the task, I immediately return to the user saying that the task started and he/she will be informed when it is done. I wonder if this task I created will cause any problems, since I returned and ended the HTTP response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using message based service bus, and a good tutorial on MSDN [Building
   Distributed Apps with NHibernate and Rhino Service Bus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796225.aspx) will be
   very useful.

Answer (score 4):

This type of "asynchronous work" isn't possible by using the `Task` type. As I mention on my blog, [`async` does not change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html); you still get one response per request, that's it!

The ideal ASP.NET app does not do any work outside of a request/response pair. There are ways to make it work [(also described on my blog)](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html), but it's almost never recommended.

The proper solution is to split up the processing. A web site (or service) should *start* the processing by placing a request into persistent storage (e.g., Azure queue), a separate worker service (e.g., Azure worker role / Win32 service) would do the polling and put the results into persistent storage (e.g., Azure table), and the web site/service could poll that.

Answer (score 0):

If you just return from a standard asp.net request then wouldn't you expect the HttpResponse to end?  Starting up a task in itself won't hold the HttpResponse open, to that you'd need to stream your response and block on the server until your task is finished which is presumably not what you want to do?

Maybe you should look at some ajax on the client that periodically pings the server to see if the task has finished, or at HTML 5 push notifications if you know your browser is going to support it.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your reply. Ending response is OK with me. I want to end it. I'm just wandering if it causes any other problem since the task I've started in my aspx class is still running. By the way triggering this functionality from client side is not an option in my case. It must be done in server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45 but imho ajax with web service much better